# A question on properties of triangles.

Tags: circles, triangles

> Find the relation between the circumradius of an obtuse angled triangle and its orthic triangle.

I tried using angles in the orthic triangle and sine law but getting stuck.
Please help me.  Would appreciate if you would give the relation using sine laws.

Answer (score 0):

I got the radius is equal to $\frac{R}{2}$.

The hint:

We can assume that our triangle is acute-angled triangle and see my solution of the following problem.

[A question with a triangle and its orthocenter in the picture.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417817/)

Let $\measuredangle ABC>90^{\circ}$, $AA_1$, $BB_1$ and $CC_1$ be altitudes of $\Delta ABC$.

Thus, $\Delta AHC$ is an acute-angled triangle and the circumrarius of $\Delta ABC$ is equal to the circumradius of $\Delta AHC$ and since $\Delta A_1B_1C_1$ is an orthic triangle of $\Delta ABC$ and of $\Delta AHC$,

we obtain that the  circumradius of the orthic triangle equal to $\frac{R}{2}$.

Comment: i have already shown it for acute. its very easy. i am having a hard time with obtuse. so please help

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar It's the easiest part! I'll add soon something in my post.

Comment: please. thank you and hurry up. ^.^

Comment: could you use sine rule and show the solution?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar You said that you have the solution for acute-angled triangle.

Comment: of course, i am asking if you could use sine rules in obtuse angled triangle and get the answer?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar Yes I can, but  It's unnecessary because I proved that we can assume that $\Delta ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle and for this triangle you have a proof.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65137/discussion-between-lokesh-sangewar-and-michael-rozenberg).