# A question with a triangle and its orthocenter in the picture.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

> Given that $\Delta ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle. $H$ is the orthocenter of the triangle. If $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ are the circumradii of $\Delta AHB$,  $\Delta BHC$ and  $\Delta CHA$ respectively  then $R_1^2+R_2^2+R_3^2-3R^2$ is?

I don't even know how to proceed. Please help me with this question.

Comment: Is $R$ the circumradius of triangle $ABC$ ?

Comment: @john nobody Oh ! My bad ! Very sorry. I correct it.

Comment: Well, it doesn't change much the substance of the problem.

Comment: According to revision history, the first version of this question is $-3R^2$ instead of $-R^2$. Furthermore, if the question is $-3R^2$, the answer is $0$ which seems much more natural.

Comment: I've edited it back to $-3R^2$ matching what's on the first version of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is $0$ because

$\measuredangle BHC+\measuredangle BAC=180^{\circ}$, $\measuredangle AHC+\measuredangle ABC=180^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle AHB+\measuredangle ACB=180^{\circ}.$

Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ be measures of angles $A$, $B$ and $C$ of our triangle.

Thus, $$\measuredangle AHC=180^{\circ}-\measuredangle HAC-\measuredangle HCA=180^{\circ}-(90^{\circ}-\gamma)-(90^{\circ}-\alpha)=\alpha+\gamma.$$

Thus, $$\measuredangle AHC+\measuredangle ABC=\alpha+\gamma+\beta=180^{\circ},$$

Which says that by law of sines for $\Delta ABC$ and for $\Delta AHC$ we obtain:
$$AC=2R\sin\beta$$ and
$$AC=2R_3\sin(180^{\circ}-\beta)=2R_3\sin\beta.$$
Thus, $R_3=R$.

Similarly, we see that $R_1=R$ and $R_2=R$.

Thus, $$R_1^2+R_2^2+R_3^2-3R^2=0.$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate and give a detailed solution?please

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar I added something. See now.

Comment: can you help me with this question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2417769/403840

Comment: How did you get AHC=180-HAC-HCA?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar A sum of measures angles of $\Delta AHC$ equal to $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: I mean how did you get HAC and HCA values?

Comment: Did you use concyclic property?

Comment: @Lokesh Sangewar Let $AA_1$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABC$. Thus from $\Delta AA_1C$ we obtain $\measuredangle HAC=90^{\circ}-\gamma$. Yes we can. Let $BH$ crosses the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ in the point $B_3$. Prove that $\Delta AHC\cong AB_3C$. From here  circumradius of $\Delta ABC$ equal to circumradius of $\Delta AB_3C$ equl to  circumradius of $\Delta AHC$.

Comment: ok and can you please help me with the other one?